# Passing object to onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to pass an object to a button's `onclick` but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I'm trying:

```
<input type='button' onclick='showTransreqForm(\"" + result.productsArray[i] + "\")' value='Go'>
```

If I print the object, `result.productsArray[i]`, just above this line, I can see all its attributes in the javascript console.

But when I print it in the `showTransreqForm` function it comes as `[object Object]` and the data doesn't seem to be there.

Just for completion this is the `showTransreqForm` function:

```
function showTransreqForm(plan) {
    console.log(plan);
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: this is the code that the button generated is part of:

```
    var planStr = "<b>Recommended Plans</b>" + "<br><br>" +
    "<form id='getTransForm' method='POST'>";
    for (i = 0; i < result.productsArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(result.productsArray[i]);
        console.log(result.productsArray[i].get("Price"));

        planStr += "plan " + (i+1) + "<br>" +
        result.productsArray[i].get("CarrierName") + ": " +
        result.productsArray[i].get("Price") + 
        "<input type='button' value='Go'  onclick='showTransreqForm(\"" + result.productsArray[i] + "\")' >" +

        "<br><br>";
    }
    planStr += "</form>";
    $(".success3").append('<br />' + planStr).show();
```

As mentioned above, the `result.productsArray[i]` prints out correctly from inside the for loop, and so does the price attribute. But it doesn't get passed correctly to the `showTransreqForm` function.

Comment: where do `result` come from?

Comment: From a Parse.com cloud code. In other words from the server.

Comment: can you show the code where you retrieve it from the server? I think it's the scope problem

Comment: but you have a typo in your code, those quotes are not necessary

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili can you show me the line of code without the quotes? pln's suggestion below doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you have to store your `result` variable in global scope. if you show us the code all about 'result` we can help further

Comment: This is coming from the server in a 'success' function. Like this: success: function(result)

Comment: I edited the question with the block of code. Basically I can't just use the line of code you offered, because the button is part of a dynamically generated string.

Comment: Of ok, you are trying to convert object in string, of course object can't passed this way

Comment: Thanks George. Making the variable global was the right move :)

Comment: your welcome, I was gonna write the solution you have already got, to pass index is right choice :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the way you have constructed the onclick. Appending string to an object will result to string.
In your case "" + object would result to "[object Object]".
Just change your code to below

```
<input type='button' onclick='showTransreqForm( result.productsArray[i])' value='Go'
```

I assume you have defined **result** variable globally.

Comment: I edited the question with the block of code. Basically I can't just use the line of code you offered, because the button is part of a dynamically generated string.

Comment: Just bind the index i instead of result.productsArray[i]. While receiving the event you just need to parse the parameter to int and use it with result.productsArray.

Comment: Thanks. I did have to define it globally, and then setting the global variable to the result, and passing the index worked.

Comment: Can anyone share the working code for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

data[0] is coming from server side.
`var task = data[0].result; <button style='padding:5px 65px;border:none;hover:cursor;' " + title + "' onclick = OpenRerunAll("+ task +")>Rerun All</button>`

but the task is passed as Object shown below
[image]